# Не понятно почему выходит ошибка в Python для НС

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, машинное-обучение

Пытаюсь обучить НС, но выдает ошибку:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_10 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (349,)

Смысл ошибки понятен. Непонятно, почему ошибка вообще появляется?

```
#МОДЕЛь, входных данных
visible = Input(shape=(8,)) 

hidden1 = Dense(70, activation='softsign')(visible)

hidden2 = Dense(80, activation='softsign')(hidden1)

hidden3 = Dense(90, activation='softsign')(hidden2)

hidden4 = Dense(70, activation='softsign')(hidden3)

outputs = Dense(349, activation='softmax')(hidden4)

model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=outputs)

#компилируем модель

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', 
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


hst = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, 
          epochs = 100, 
          batch_size = 2000, 
          verbose=1, 
          shuffle=True, 
          validation_data=(X_test,Y_test))
```

Вот, что храниться в Менеджере переменных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе вывод команды: print(model.summary()) ?

Comment: картинка есть..

Comment: в ошибке указан слой `dense_10`, который отсутствует в архитектуре вашей НС

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо. Я попробую. Еще заметила ошибку, что у меня sparse_categorical_crossentropy. А там вроде задаются параметры по другому.

Comment: _картинка есть_ - избегайте приводить код и данные картинками вместо текста. Только это удержало меня проголосовать (+1) за ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте построить НС следующим способом:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(70, input_shape=(X.shape[1],), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(80, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(90, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(70, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(Y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
```